# How do I parse a structured string data(nearing JSON) in textarea to retrieve its required attributes?

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following in HTML code:

```
</div></td><td align='center' rowspan=2><textarea rows='15' name='bibtext' id='bibtext' readonly cols='40'>
@book{book:12,
   title =     {title goes here},
   author =    {author goes here},
   other but non-relevant
}</textarea>
```

To retrieve the contents of `id='bibtext'` I use:

```
document.getElementById("bibtext").InnerText
```

And I get:

```
@book{book:12,
   title =     {title goes here},
   author =    {author goes here},
   other but non-relevant
}
```

But how do I get the content of `title` (that is `title goes here`)? I have heard of `document.querySelector` but I don't know if it is applicable here.

Comment: I think you shouldn't populate/render data into the Textarea like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
var value = document.getElementById("bibtext").innerText;
value = JSON.parse( value.substring( value.indexOf("{") ) ).title;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use two input text for the title and the author and one text area for "other but non-relevant". It d be pointless to parse the content of your text area to get the title and the author when you can simply put them in seperate inputs

Comment: It's not my HTML code and your comment is not an answer.

Comment: Well it's just an advice so you can do it in an easier way. I'm just trying to help, no need to be rude :).

Comment: I didn't mean to be rude. In SO if you have some comment or advice you are supposed to provide it as a comment to the question rather than as a answer. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Well i'd like to but i have not enough rep to comment atm so... i do as i can :)

Answer (score 0):

`document.querySelector` works only for DOM (parsed HTML). In your case the contents of the textarea is just string. It is not even JSON (although it looks kind of similar) - so lets try to parse it with regex:

```
var text = document.getElementById("bibtext").value;
text.match(/title.*/)[0]; // "title =     {title goes here},"
```

You can slice it further with regex as you desire... :)

`InnerText` doesn't work for me in Chrome, therefore I use `value` to get to the contents of textarea.

Answer (score 0):

You can Try this.

```
var c=document.getElementById("bibtext").InnerText;
var a=c.split(",");
console.log(a[1].substring(a[1].indexOf("{")+1,a[1].length-1));
```